# find objects of specific class from a List<>

Tags: c#, generic-list

I've got a base class, say called `Fruits`. I then have a few child classes of that, say `Banana:Fruit`, `Apple:Fruit`, etc.

I then have a list of objects of different types, Banana, Apple, whatever. That looks like this:

```
List<Fruits> f = new List<Fruits>{new Banana(), new Banana(), new Apple(), new Banana()};
```

I want a function that can take a list of fruits as well as a type, and give me a list with only that type's objects in the list. So if I call `find_obj(f, Banana)`, (or something) it should give me back a list containing only Bananas.

I might be showing extreme ignorance here, and I apologise. Is this even possible? I know I could do something like this if I know the class beforehand:

```
public List<Fruit> GimmeBanana(List<Fruit> f)
{
     List<Fruit> Output=new List<Fruit>{ };
     foreach(Fruit fr in f)
     {
         if (fr is Banana){ Output.Add(fr); }
     }
}
```

But I don't know how to make that work for *Any* class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Such a method already exists in the framework - [`OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
List<Banana> bananas = f.OfType<Banana>().ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome! that's much easier (and shorter) than where I was headed.

Answer (score 2):

you need a generic method like:

```
    public List<T> GimmeAnyOfType<T>(List<Fruit> f)
    {
        return f.OfType<T>().ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you should use `OfType` as noted by other answers, as a learning experience, here is how I would write your method:

```
public IEnumerable<Banana> GimmeBananas(List<Fruit> f)
{
     if (f == null) yield break; //depending on what business logic you're looking for.
     foreach(Fruit fr in f)
     {
         if (fr is Banana) yield return fr;
     }
}
```

Comment: +1 - foreach tends to be faster than linq (depending on the query), plus this gives the developer an opportunity to perform business logic without looping twice.

Comment: You might want to replace Banana with T and add <T> to the method signature.  Makes it generic, which is what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LINQ OfType Operator to select from a collection only elements with the matching type.

```
class Fruit { }
class Banana : Fruit{}
class Apple : Fruit{}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fruits = new List<Fruit> { new Banana(),  new Banana(), new Apple(), new Fruit() };
    int bananas = fruits.OfType<Banana>().Count(); // 2
    int apples = fruits.OfType<Apple>().Count(); // 1
    int fruitc = fruits.OfType<Fruit>().Count(); // 4
    int exactFruits = GetOfExactType<Fruit,Fruit>(fruits).Count();  // 1
}


static IEnumerable<V> GetOfExactType<T, V>(IEnumerable<T> coll)
{
    foreach (var x in coll)
    {
        if (x.GetType().TypeHandle.Value == typeof(V).TypeHandle.Value)
        {
            yield return (V)(object)x;
        }
    }
}
```

This operator does only work if you have a flat derivation hierachy. If you have e.g. Apples as base class derived from fruit and you have specialized apples like GoldenDelicius, RedDelicus, ... and you want to count all apples which are of the type apple but not derived ones you cannot do that with the OfType operator. For this you still need an extra function. In the example it is called GetOfExactType.